# How to remove whitespace with prettier?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import React from 'react';

import { Provider } from 'mobx-react-lite';

import appStore from './store'; 

import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen'; 



export default function App() {


  return (
    <Provider store={appStore}>


      <HomeScreen />



    </Provider>


    
  );
}
```

just a sample code, but by default, prettier does not remove whitespaces for me, how do i configure prettier to remove unnecessary whitespace and trailing whitespace? thanks

my prettier config

```
{
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "printWidth": 80
}
```

Comment: Did you test prettier with another format error? Did it worked?

Comment: what do you mean another format error ?